# Is there an equivalent of before_action :authenticate_user! for Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is there an equivalent of `before_action :authenticate_user!` for Active Admin to redirect to the admin login page if a non admin user visit a page?

For instance, with devise I do

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show]
```

I would like to do the same check for an admin user.

Any clue?

Comment: If set up correctly, Active Admin should do this "out of the box". As noted here https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html, the setting to authenticate the admin_user is set in the initializer for Active Admin. It does this for all resources under /admin. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up `ActiveAdmin` with a `CanCanAdapter` authorization_adapter for which you can configure the method to be called if the user is not authorized, check the documentation [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/49a7507b45062c1ad37efee75338f8d3cea602cf/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md#using-the-cancan-adapter)